# How to build linux container from Windows in a Linux VM?

Tags: python, windows, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I set up a VM running Fedora 31 and installed docker on it. Exposed all the necessary ports and then installed the docker client application in a Debian WSL runtime. Exported the necessary env vars and everything appears to be good so far, if I issue:

```
docker run --rm python:3.8-slim python -V
```

I see:

> Python 3.8.3

But when I try to build a "real" of a project that otherwise builds perfectly fine under a fully-linux environment, I get lots of wanings like these:

```
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (df8922)…
Failed to load paths: /bin/sh: 1: /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/bin/python: not found

Output:
Failed to load paths: /bin/sh: 1: /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/bin/python: not found

Output:
Failed to load paths: /bin/sh: 1: /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-4PlAip0Q/bin/python: not found

Output:
Ignoring atomicwrites: markers 'sys_platform == "win32"' don't match your environment
Ignoring colorama: markers 'sys_platform == "win32"' don't match your environment
Ignoring pypiwin32: markers 'sys_platform == "win32" and python_version >= "3.6"' don't match your environment
```

And ultimately fails with something like this:

```
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32==227 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-4jkbeenf-requirements/pipenv-jlzeswcc-requirement.txt (line 1))
ERROR: Couldn't install package: pywin32
 Package installation failed...
```

Apparently, it tries to install deps as if it were running in Windows, but how do I tell the daemon to assume it runs in linux (like the VM)?

The goal is to use this python image as a remote virtual environment in PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like that you want to run docker on linux vm but you installed docker desktop for windows.  I think you need docker-engine for linux OS if you want docker on linux vm.

If you want to docker on windows and to run linux, install docker for windows desktop on windows OS and switch docker desktop mode to wsl mode.